# Can browsers be forced to cache HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, web, caching

I'm getting married and instead of printing wedding invitation cards, I made a webpage. One of my friends created a subfolder (`/var/www/web/myname`) on his web server, and I uploaded my files (HTML, CSS, JS) via SSH.

It is important: I have access to only that folder, therefore I cannot use any database and do any server-side modification! My only toolset is HTML directives and client-side JS.

Since it's public anybody is able to see it, but I don't want that. That's why I AES encrypted the HTML code of my page and I made a login page. After entering the a valid password (its hash is stored in JS source file) the JS script decrypts the AES encrypted string (that is also stored in the JS source file) by using the password as the key and it changes the actual page to the now-decrypted HTML code by calling `document.open()`, `document.write()`, and `document.close()`.

Is there any way to force the browser to cache the actual HTML code to avoid re-typing the password each time they open the page?

Some of you requested the JS "login" code:

```
var hashString = "sha256_hash_of_the_password"; 
var indexPage = "aes_enrypted_string_of_base64_coded_html"; // The original one is quite long...

document.getElementById("password-box").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("password-box").classList.remove("pw-bad");
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("login-button").click();
    }
});

function buttonListener()
{
    var password = document.getElementById("password-box").value;
    if(password !== "") {
        if(CryptoJS.SHA256(password) == hashString.toLowerCase()) {
            var indexDecrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(indexPage, password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            var parsedWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(indexDecrypt);
            var parsedStr = parsedWordArray.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

            document.open('text/html');
            document.write(parsedStr);
            document.close();
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("password-box").value = "";
        document.getElementById("password-box").classList.add("pw-bad");
    }
    document.getElementById("password-box").focus();  
}
```

I know it's a silly thing, please don't judge me. :)

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your JavaScript.

Comment: You can store the password locally instead, either with a cookie or localStorage.

Comment: there is better/standard ways to login/auth a user without needing to encrypt the code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I know, but I don't have access to the web sever itself (databse, etc.), so I can only use a static HTML page.

Comment: whats stopping someone simply adding via dev tools, true to the if statement and then replacing `password` with `hashString.toLowerCase()` in decrypt.. just saying

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't get your point. `hashString.toLowerCase()` doesn't decrypt the original HTML, `password` does. Replacing `password` with `hashString.toLowerCase()` could be useful if hashing function would be invertable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to cache a page, cache control headers, or service workers for example. That said, caching a page for authentication purposes is generally not the right approach. You would instead want to save some kind of *authentication tokens* (JWT, session cookies, etc), for further re-authentication.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

```js
// Once authenticated using password
document.cookie = 'someKey=someValue'

// For a returning use
function getCookie(name) {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
  return (cookies.reduce((t, c) => {
    const entry = c.split('=')
    t[entry[0]] = entry[1]
    return t
  }, {}))[name]
}

if (getCookie('someKey') === 'someValue') {
  // authenticated
}
```

Comment: @prodx The security in place here can be bypassed very easily, if your requirements are very basic I would recommend keeping it simple and simply saving/flagging what you need with a `cookie`